# Implementing mutate within a function called with variables

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval, nse

I'd like to call a function several times with different variables, each time setting a value to a new variable in the data frame. Here is my failed attempt. I appreciate any help!

```
dat <- tibble(score1 = runif(10), score2 = score1 * 2)

call_mutate_with_vars <- function(df, var1, var2, var3) {
  df <- 
    df %>%
    mutate({{var3}} := ifelse({{var1}} >= {{var2}},0,{{var2}} - {{var1}}))
  df
}

call_mutate_with_vars(dat,"score1","score2","newscore")
```

I receive this error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `newscore`.
i `newscore = ifelse("score1" >= "score2", 0, "score2" - "score1")`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: With `{{}}`, you need to pass unquoted for the columns to be evaluated i.e. `call_mutate_with_vars(dat,score1,score2,"newscore")` should work

Answer (score 4):

The embracing operator `{{` is meant for variables passed as symbols (i.e., `fx(var)`, not `fx("var")`). If you need to pass your variables as characters, you can instead use the `.data` pronoun.

So you can either pass symbols to your current function:

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)

call_mutate_with_vars <- function(df, var1, var2, var3) {
  df %>%
    mutate(
      {{var3}} := ifelse(
        {{var1}} >= {{var2}},
        0,
        {{var2}} - {{var1}}
      )
    )
}

call_mutate_with_vars(dat, score1, score2, newscore)

#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>    score1 score2 newscore
#>     <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 0.266   0.531   0.266 
#>  2 0.372   0.744   0.372 
#>  3 0.573   1.15    0.573 
#>  4 0.908   1.82    0.908 
#>  5 0.202   0.403   0.202 
#>  6 0.898   1.80    0.898 
#>  7 0.945   1.89    0.945 
#>  8 0.661   1.32    0.661 
#>  9 0.629   1.26    0.629 
#> 10 0.0618  0.124   0.0618
```

Or rewrite the function to handle characters:

```
call_mutate_with_chr_vars <- function(df, var1, var2, var3) {
  df %>% 
    mutate(
      !!var3 := ifelse(                  # note use of !! unquote operator
        .data[[var1]] >= .data[[var2]],  # to use character as name
        0,
        .data[[var2]] - .data[[var1]]
      )
    )
}

call_mutate_with_chr_vars(dat, "score1", "score2", "newscore")

#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>    score1 score2 newscore
#>     <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 0.266   0.531   0.266 
#>  2 0.372   0.744   0.372 
#>  3 0.573   1.15    0.573 
#>  4 0.908   1.82    0.908 
#>  5 0.202   0.403   0.202 
#>  6 0.898   1.80    0.898 
#>  7 0.945   1.89    0.945 
#>  8 0.661   1.32    0.661 
#>  9 0.629   1.26    0.629 
#> 10 0.0618  0.124   0.0618
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The ["Programming with dplyr"](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) vignette is a nice reference for these sorts of problems.