# Getting variables from data for functions in R

Tags: r, function

I am trying to create a function in R. I am a bit confused on how I am supposed to use the variables from the data in the function. Say I have a data frame of:

```
tb <- tibble(x = 1:5)
```

and I create a function:

```r
f <- function(data, z){
# some function
}
```

I then want to be able to just do:

```
f(data = tb, z = x)
```

but I get "Error in f(data = tb, z = x): object x not found". I want to be able to do something like the lm function where I tell it the data and can then reference the variables in the function as so:

```r
lm(mpg~cyl+disp, data = mtcars)
```

But I'm not sure how to make this work inside the function. Any help on how I can do this or if this makes sense?

Comment: Working with df variable names in functions can be tricky. The *[Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)* vignette is a good place to start. For many tidyverse functions, the embracing operator `{{` can help. See [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71384696/17303805).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not tagged `dplyr` nor `tidyverse` so I assume base R answers are on topic.

## Base R

With base R to get a variable passed unquoted, therefore unevaluated, to a function, use `deparse(substitute(.))` in the function. This also works with the new pipe operator introduced in R 4.1.

```r
tb <- data.frame(x = 1:5)

f <- function(data, z){
  z <- deparse(substitute(z))
  data[[z]] * 2
}

f(tb, z = x)
#> [1]  2  4  6  8 10

tb |> f(z = x)
#> [1]  2  4  6  8 10
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

## Package `dplyr`

With package `dplyr` the function above works but the idiomatic way is with double braces `{{`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

g <- function(data, z){
  data %>% mutate(x = {{z}} * 2)
}

tb %>% f(x)
#> [1]  2  4  6  8 10

tb %>% g(x)
#>    x
#> 1  2
#> 2  4
#> 3  6
#> 4  8
#> 5 10
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This worked perfectly for base and tidyverse thank you!